# Like Button: Make Facebook NOT take specific images

Tags: image, share, facebook-like, selection

I'd still like my users to have a **choice** of image to select when sharing links from my site but I would like to **restrict** certain images from showing in the Facebook sharer. I don't want to select a specific image using meta tags (this has been suggested often).

Would appreciate any help!

*EDIT (9 Jul 2012): This question is not an exact duplicate to any others on stack overflow. I asked for a method to restrict images from showing without specifying OG or meta tags, unlike others who have simply asked how to show a specific image. Why do people on this site assume (and rate my question down) before even reading it carefully and considering whether it is a duplicate.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to specify multiple og:image tags of images that you want to allow and then the user will be able to choose from the images you select.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help! Was hoping there was an easier way to do it (like blocking specific images) but it seems that is not the case.